# I want to fix the roll without missing the default 3d control

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am using Forge viewer on mobile device.
Default Forge viewer is rolling on mobile device when moving to a position using pinch gesture.I research how to fix the roll (reference to [Fixing pinch-zoom in Forge viewer applications - Through the Interface](https://www.keanw.com/2017/04/fixing-pinch-zoom-in-forge-viewer-applications.html), [GitHub - wallabyway/forge-pinch-zoom: customized iPad/IPhone/Android pinch zoom touch controls for ForgeViewer](https://github.com/wallabyway/forge-pinch-zoom)), but it is missing default 3D control. For example, it's missing pan motion when I use two-finger gesture. I want to fix the roll without missing the default 3d control. How do I do it?

I have tried to disable to rotate gesture in GestureHandler. (gestureHandler.setGestureParameter(); )
I have checked to invalidate pinch gesture correctly;  `gestureHandler.setGestureParameter('pinch', 'enable', false)`
But I have checked that it is still valid to roll, regardless if the enable is false;  `gestureHandler.setGestureParameter('rotate', 'enable', false)`.

```js
let orbit = viewer.impl.controls.getActiveTool()
let gestureHandler = orbit.controller.getActiveTools()[2]
gestureHandler.setGestureParameter('rotate', 'enable', false)
```

I have another question.
It emits the pinch event after I pinch gesture. I understand this behavior.
It is not emitting the roll event after I do the roll gesture while doing the pinching gesture. I can't understand this behavior.
Maybe there are the multiple methods controlling the camera roll. I can't figure out the method to control the roll on mobile device anywhere.

Comment: ah - let me take a look...

Comment: I just double checked the demo github/wallabyway on my iPhone and it seems to be working with 3D roll as before.  I'm not fully understanding why your drawing is not activating into 3D mode, perhaps it's a special model?  Any chance you could share a live demo link ?

Comment: For your second question...  are you talking about the roll UI that appears when you click the orbit button, using mouse events?  ...Because, touch events, use a different code-path, than mouse-events, to control the camera.  Hence why the roll-UI does not appear.  Pinch-zoom, can handle the roll, zoom and pan all with the two finger pinch-zoom gesture.  A mouse cannot do that.  hence, there was no need to re-use the roll UI.